# How I can create a row repeated as many times as a previous variable?

Tags: sql, macros, sas, rows

I am trying to write a code in SAS. I have a dataset as follows:

```
data one;

input  CLI  date date9.  time time8. ;
format date date9. time hhmm8. ;
cards;
5 01apr2014 10:00:00 
6 01apr2014 11:00:00 
10 01apr2014 12:00:00 
4 02Apr2014 10:00:00 
20 02apr2014 11:00:00 
12 02apr2014 12:00:00 
;
run;
```

I would like to obtain a dataset as follows:

```
data two;

date time New_cli
01apr2014 10:00:00 1
01apr2014 10:00:00 1
01apr2014 10:00:00 1
01apr2014 10:00:00 1
01apr2014 10:00:00 1
01apr2014 11:00:00 1
01apr2014 11:00:00 1
01apr2014 11:00:00 1
01apr2014 11:00:00 1
01apr2014 11:00:00 1
01apr2014 11:00:00 1
.
.
.
02Apr2014 10:00:00 1
02Apr2014 10:00:00 1
02Apr2014 10:00:00 1
02Apr2014 10:00:00 1
.
.
```

As it is, each observation in data "one" should be repeated CLI times in "two"(e.g. the first observation in one 1/04 10 am should be repeated 5 times in two, the second one 6 etc..)
There is some one that could help me? many thanks!

Comment: The code you posted is not properly [indented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262), making it very hard to read and understand. Always take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. Please [edit] your question until it is easy to read and understand. Also read the article on [ask]. Well formatted questions have a higher chance of getting good answers.

Comment: Did you try a `DO` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `do` loop from `1 to CLI`, and use an `output` statement within the loop to output a row for every iteration of the loop. SAS will automatically resolve `CLI` to the value that it holds, and run the `do` loop exactly that many times.

```
data want;
    set have;

    do i = 1 to CLI;
        new_cli = 1;
        output;           
    end;

    drop i;
run;
```